# Add a css library to a php project thru composer, but it does not work

Tags: php, composer-php, yui-pure-css

I want to use a light css library [pure](https://github.com/pure-css/pure-site). When I manually add it into my php/html file it works:

```
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-oAOxQR6DkCoMliIh8yFnu25d7Eq/PHS21PClpwjOTeU2jRSq11vu66rf90/cZr47" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

After I require it thru composer:

```
composer require yahoo/purecss
```

the composer indeed adds the library to my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "yahoo/purecss": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

But **it does not work**.

The `autoload.php` is included:

```
<?php session_start();  
include "vendor/autoload.php";
```

**What's wrong?**

Comment: lemme get this straight .. you want to use composer, a PHP package manager to autoload the css? That's not how it works.. you still need to call it the same way you did with the `<link>` - Composer deals with PHP - not CSS/HMTL (in terms of autoloading)

Comment: @treyBake, thanks. You might make it an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin `purecss` is the node module so it will not work with PHP composer. Follow this link https://github.com/pure-css/pure to install the node module if you are using node in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Composer deals with PHP dependencies. Pure have made it installable via composer, but all that does is dump the files into your vendor folder. The rest will be up to you!